# Trying to create carousel in React Js but Function shows as is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, carousel, background-image

I am trying to create a div that has three cycling background images every 3 seconds. Now as I wrote my code it is showing me an error that says   Line 13:3:  'startCarousel' is not defined  no-undef
Line 17:1:  'startCarousel' is not defined  no-undef. start Carrousel is the name of the function, Previously I have used this same code in another project but only through Vanilla JS. Am I forgetting to post something ?. my code is below

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/Main.scss'
import GirlsWriting from '../assets/girls-writing.webp'
import KidsLearning from '../assets/kids-group-learning.jpg'
import KidsWorking from '../assets/kids-working.jpg';

const Main = () => {


    const images = [{ GirlsWriting }, { KidsLearning }, { KidsWorking }]
    const goodCitizens = document.querySelector('.good-citizens');
    const interval = setInterval(function () {
        startCarousel();
    }, 3000);
    var index = 1;

    startCarousel = () => {
        goodCitizens.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[index++]})`;
        goodCitizens.classList.remove('carousel');
        void goodCitizens.offsetWidth;
        goodCitizens.classList.add('carousel');
        if (index > images.length - 1) index = 0;
    };


return(
    <main>
        <div className='good-citizens carousel'>

        </div>

    </main>

)
```

Comment: I don't know much about this language, but shouldn't you define startCarousel before calling it?

Comment: I am on the same boat, I am barely starting React. by defining you mean creating a constant with the function as its value ?